# How to create a table for a user in a Database

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services

I am creating an mobile application. In this app, I have created a Login and Register activity. I have also created a online Database using AWS(Amazon Web Service) to store all the login information of the user upon registering.

In my database, i have a table called 'users'. This table holds the following fields "fname","lname","username","password". This part works and successfully stores data from my phone to the database.

for example,

```
   | fname  |  lname | username | password | 
   | ------ | ------ | -------- | -------- |
   | john   |  doe   | jhon123  | 1234     |
```

Inside the app, I have an option where the user may click on "Start Log", which will record a start and end values on a seekBar.

How can i create a table under a user who is logged in.

> (Essentially, i want to be able to create multiple tables under a user.)

for example,

This table should be under the user "john123":

```
   | servo  |  Start | End | 
   | ------ | ------ | --- | 
   |    1   |   21   |  30 |
   |    2   |   30   |  11 |
   |    3   |   50   |  41 |  
   |    4   |    0   |  15 |
```

I know its a confusing question, but

> i am essentially just trying to have multiple tables linked to a user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As to:

> How to create a table for a user in a Database

Here are some GUI tools you might find useful:

- MySQL - [MySQL Workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/)
- PostgreSQL - [PG Admin](https://www.pgadmin.org/)

As for creating a separate table for each user, refer to @Polymath's answer. There is no benefit in creating separate tables for each user (you might as well use a `json` file).

What you should do is create a `logs` table that has a `user_id` attribute referencing the `id` in the `users` table.

```
 -------------------------------------------------------
| id | fname  |  lname | username | password            | 
| -- | ------ | ------ | -------- | ------------------- |
| 1  | john   |  doe   | jhon123  | encrypted(password) |
 -------------------------------------------------------
  |______
         |
         V
 ---------------------------------------
| id | user_id | servo_id | start | end |
| -- | ------- | -------- | ----- | --- |
| 1  | 1       | 1        | 21    | 30  |
| 2  | 1       | 2        | 30    | 11  |
 ---------------------------------------
```

You should also look into [database normalization](http://www.computerweekly.com/tutorial/Database-normalization-in-MySQL-Four-quick-and-easy-steps) as your "`john123`" table is not in `3NF`. The servo should be decomposed out of `logs` table if it will be logged by multiple users or multiple times (*which I'm guessing is the case for you*).

Answer (score 2):

In reading this I wonder if your design is right. It sounds like you are trying to create a table for each user.  I also wonder how scalable it is to have a unique table per user.  if you scale to millions of users you will have millions of tables to manage and will probably need a separate index table to find the right table for the user.  Why a table for each? Why not a single table with the UserID as a use key value. You can extract the data just by filtering on the UserID.

```
Select * FROM UsersData ORDER BY DateTime WHERE User == UserID
```

However I will leave that for you to ponder.

You mentioned that this is a Mobile App.  I think what you need to do is look at AWS Federated access and Cognito which will allow you to Identify a user using federate Identities.  Pass the User unique Id , plus a temporary (one use) credentials linked to an access Role.  Combined this way, you can scale to millions of users with full authentication without managing millions of accounts.

RL